# How to compare two IP Addresses and find out if they match fully or partially or they do not match at all

Tags: python

I need to compare two Different IP subnet and show result if it is full match, partial match or no match.

I need to use Python.

Can break IP into list but it becomes tricky when there is a subnet involved.
For example:

I need to compare a and b where a = 10.10.1.2/25 and b = 10.10.1.6/24 and show the result. I am new to python and not sure how to achieve this task.

Comment: In the example you have mentioned - are `a` and `b` a partial match or no match? How do you define partial match?

Comment: FYI, in Python3 there is [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ipaddress module of python (in-built)

```
from  ipaddress import ip_interface
# since you have provided interface address
ip1 = ip_interface.ip_address('10.10.1.2/24')
ip2 = ip_interface.ip_address('10.10.1.6/24')
print(ip1 == ip2)
# answer would be False
```

Comment: it is in python 3.X not sure for python 2.7.X

Comment: it is python 3.7.x

Comment: This will give an error. in_interface is a method of ipaddress, as is ip_address. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html. If you remove the .ip_address it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python 3 ipaddress library. I guess you need to check if networks of `a` and `b` IP addresses overlap.

If we construct [Interface Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#interface-objects), each one will have it's own network attribute accessible through `.network`.

```
from ipaddress import ip_interface
a = ip_interface('10.10.1.2/25')
b = ip_interface('10.10.1.6/24')

print(b.network.overlaps(a.network))
```

**Output**:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
> True
```

Answer (score -1):

in the spirit of helping you figure out things instead of providing the solution, try using

- `str.split()` ([see description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)) to break down the IP-addresses into substrings,
- then `==` statements to compare them and
- `if`, `elif` to proceed further.

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: I already tried this. The problem was with CIDR value and Partial Maching.